# How to get IP from a Connection object in Cx_Oracle

Tags: oracle, connection, cx-oracle

In cx_Oracle, I obtained a `Connection` object using tnsnames.ora

Example:

```
conn = cx_Oracle.connect ('scott', 'tiger', 'DBNAME')
```

I'm trying to get an IP from a connection object (= conn), but I can not figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

It is practically impossible. Even OCI does not support it. There was a trick in OCI to convert OCI Connection struct into the old Oracle7 connection context, and this structure contains "file handle" number for TCP socket to the database. From this file/socket descriptor you could get IP.

If you use tnsnames.ora you can easily parse it. But in case of Oracle RAC you 1st connect SCAN lister, this one will send you just redirect packet to some cluster node. TCP connection to scan listener is closed and a new TCP connection is opened, based on information received from SCAN listener.